# React passing props in Render with outdated State

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

In the constructor for my React class, I make a call to my API. I use the data from my API to change the state of my class and the information from my state is passed as props to a component I have in the render method.

My constructor:

```
   constructor(props){
    super(props)
  
    this.state = {
        description:"",
        amount: 0,
        createdAt: 0,
        note:"",
    }
    
   
   this.callAPI() 
   

}
```

As you can see, I call my API using the callAPI method.
Here is callAPI()

```
callAPI(){
  
    const expenseID = this.props.match.url.substring(19, this.props.match.url.length);

    let url = "http://localhost:8080/singleExpense?email="+encodeURIComponent(this.props.email)+"&id="+encodeURIComponent(expenseID)
  
    let h = new Headers({
        "Authorization": this.props.token
    })
    let req = new Request(url, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: h
    })
    fetch(req).then(async(response,error)=>{
        if(error){
            console.log(error)
            return
        }
        const parseResponse = await response.json()
       
        this.setState(()=>{
            return({
                description: parseResponse.description,
                amount: parseResponse.amount,
                createdAt: parseResponse.createdAt,
                note: parseResponse.note
            })
        })
        console.log(this.state)
    })
}
```

I fetch some data and update my state

Here is my render method

```
 render(){
   
    
    return(
        <div>
            <ExpensForm description = {this.state.description} amount = {this.state.amount} createdAt = {this.state.createdAt} note = {this.state.note}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The props such as description and amount I am passing as props is not the one from the updated state with the API call, instead, it is the default one.

How do I make it so that I can get the data from my API, update the state and THEN pass it as props on the component I use in the render method.

Please let me know if you need any other information.

As requested, the Expense form component's constructor

```
export default class ExpenseForm extends React.Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props)
    console.log(props)
    this.state = {
        description: props?props.description:"",
        note: props.expense?props.expense.note:"",
        amount: props.expense?(props.expense.amount/100).toString():"",
        createdAt: props.expense?moment(props.expense.createdAt) :moment(),
        calendarFocused: false,
        errorState: ""
    }
}
```

Comment: 1 - You're sure there's no error right? (Since you just return if there is an error). 2 - How are you checking that the props are updated? Maybe the problem is in the child component?

Comment: There is no error. I have a console.log at the end of callAPI that prints the current state and that state is the updated one with the correct info from the API. But the ExpenseForm component is not receiving these updated values and instead the default state is being passed. Hope this answers your questions, please let me know if I was not clear enough.

Comment: We might need to see the ExpenseForm component

Comment: It is a huge component, I have updated the question with the constructor of that component.

Comment: I believe that reveals the issue - you are copying props to state in the child component's constructor, thus it only happens once. What you should probably be doing is just reading from the props in the child component's `render` method - don't use state in the child component unless there's a good reason. If that state needs to be updated, it can be done in the parent with `setState` and the child component's `render` method will then see the props update.